# Backup Organisation?

Tags: app, design, backup

I have been developing an app in a dev org. It's fairly complex and has 24+ objects and various workflows etc.. However I want to make some fairly big changes to the object relationships and before doing so I'd like a copy of the "design" of that app.

I tried workbench, created a package in SF and then exported it but some stuff didn't come along for the ride because it uses groups or references things like profiles. Exactly what is missing I've not gone through but some workflows for sure.

Any idea of the best method to take a snapshot of the org as it stands in a fashion that could be restored or is the way I've done it the only real solution?

Comment: Use force.com IDE or similar tools to grab the metadata of objects and workflows or any other component.Use version system like GIT etc to keep remote copy of your work.This way you will always be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party solutions (such as [OwnBackup](https://www.ownbackup.com/products/backup-for-salesforce)). This tool will allow you to backup your data & metadata automatically on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like https://gearset.com/features to backup your metadata to a Git repository. You can also use this to download a .zip if you want to place it somewhere else...